# Ubuntu 14.04 Ethernet Networks

Tags: network-manager, ethernet

On Ubuntu 13.10, I had to Ethernet networks configured: 'Auto' and 'Work'. When on my company network, I would manually go up and switch to the 'Work' setting (which would have the IP address, DNS settings..). However, on ubuntu 14.04, the network manager applet only displays the wireless and vpn settings and not the Ethernet settings. I have not found another way to switch the network. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has bothered me too, and I have not found a workaround that doesn't involve installing an additional application.  In my case, I decided on `wicd`, which is a single manager for both wired and wireless configurations.  It's worked pretty well for me in solving the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

`Network Connections` -> `Add` -> `Ethernet` -> `Create` -> Fill all desired fields -> `Save` 
Now you have second (apart from default) connection and while wired connection is present you can switch between them with default network widget.
[image]